# Relatório das top pages de todos os tempos, na ultima semana - Google Analytics

Tags: data, google-analytics-api

estou com uma dúvida no analytics. Esses dias um dos posts de um blog que eu gerencio, entrou nos top pages da semana. A questão é que este post, é de 2016.

O que eu gostaria de fazer, após perceber que tem conteúdo antigo gerando muito tráfego, é renovar o conteúdo para que continue a servir para novos usuários. Neste caso, eu preciso de um relatório que me mostre quais posts dos anos anteriores a 2018, por exemplo, mais bombaram nos últimos 3 meses.

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Eu até tentei criar alguns reports (inclusive custom reports para mesclar dimesions), mas todos faltam algo e estou me perdendo para agrupar as infos.

Answer (score -4):

Se você filtrar, inicialmente, as Top Pages < 2018, você terá o resultados dos posts antigos que bombaram. E aí, pela URL ou título da página, pegar essa lista e filtrar ela dentro dos Top Pages dos últimos 3 meses. Assim você terá os posts antigos que bombaram nos últimos 3 meses.

Aí vai só da tecnologia que você vai usar: talvez um Data Studio, Power BI, XLS ou até dentro do próprio Analytics mesmo. Cada um com seu nível de dificuldade e com seu nível de entrega. HEHE

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).